# Purpose of logical operators on strings in Javascript

Tags: javascript, string, jqgrid, operators

I have stumbled across a bit of code that I was hoping someone could explain to me.

This is used in the context of jqGrid.

```
onSelectRow: function(id){ 
     if(id && id!==lastsel){ 
          jQuery('#rowed3').jqGrid('restoreRow',lastsel);
          jQuery('#rowed3').jqGrid('editRow',id,true); 
          lastsel=id; 
     } 
},
```

Why use logical operators on a string in javascript as shown above? Is this simply a bug or is there some functionality here that I dont understand?

Code is taken from http://trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/rowedex3.html

Full example http://trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html > Row editing > Using events

Comment: what string are you questioning? `#rowed3`? `lastsel` and `id` both appear to be numbers, most likely integers of some sort

Comment: id && id is what I am questioning

Comment: It's `id` and `id !== lastsel`, not `id && id`. `if (id)` in itself is already a perfectly good condition.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The variables should be numeri, though, the conditional would work either way.

### *`if(id && id !== lastsel)`*

---

1. **The first `id` is saying that it must have a value.**  The value also has to be truthy.  A value is *`truthy`* if it is not *`falsy`*, which means it just can't be one of the following (borrowed from [11heavens.com](http://11heavens.com/falsy-and-truthy-in-javascript)):

   - `false`
   - `null`
   - `undefined`
   - The empty string `''`
   - The number `0`
   - The number `NaN` (`NaN` is of type number)

   **Note:** You will see the same kind of comparisons to `true` elsewhere in JavaScript, specifically for/while loops:

   ```
   /*1*/ while(id){...} // while id is true, do something
   /*2*/ for(;id;){...} // same thing, without the incrementation or variable definition
   ```
2. **The second part is saying the id can't be equal the lastsel**, which is the last id that was used. `!==` is special in JavaScript meaning it must compare value and type, whereas `!=` just compares value:

   - `a == b` : value of `a` equals value of `b`
   - `a != b` : value of `a` does not equal value of `b`
   - `a === b` : value of `a` equals value of `b` and type of `a` equals type of `b`
   - `a !== b` : value of `a` does not equal value of `b` and type of `a` does not equal type of `b`

### Edit

---

Additonally, it might help to think of the expression if you saw it in parentheses:
`if( (id) && (id !== lastsel) )`

Comment: Small comment to the "Edit" part of your answer: `!==` has higher precedence as `&&` (see for example https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence) and `&&` work left-to-right. So no bracket reqired.

Comment: Well the parens aren't required... it's just a way of grouping to think about it logically.  I don't know why i said rtl, you're right.  Maybe cuz it was 3-4am and I was probably thinking about assignment operators? The precedence is the key factor here.  I removed that bit. +1

Comment: Not a problem. I understand. Sometimes if on write quickly an answer and to some other things parallel one can easy make small errors. Now all is fixed and it is better for other who will read the text sometime later. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Well, why not?

```
(id) && (id !== lastsel)    // parentheses added for logical emphasis
```

This says `if (id is trueish) and (not equal to lastsel)`. "Trueish" means it's not `false`, `undefined` or anything else *`falsy`*. `if (id)` is equivalent to `if (id == true)`. `id` doesn't have to be a string (and as comments point out it probably never is), and this check makes sure it's not something it's not supposed to be. It's checking a *variable*, not a string.

Answer (score 0):

So this is saying that id has to be defined and not equal to lastsel.